# What is The difference between these Convert hexToByte in Java and c#

Tags: c#, hex, byte, apdu, converters

Good afternoon, 
I need to know what is the differences between

Java Code:

```
public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character
                .digit(s.charAt(i + 1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}
```

from this

C# Code:

```
public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String hex)
{
    int NumberChars = hex.Length;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
        bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
    return bytes;
}
```

If i send Parameter "A4"

Return:

C#: 164, Java: -94

I need help becouse i need to send APDU Paremeters and i dont know if my problem is this.

Thanks too much.

Comment: -94? Are java bytes signed? 0xA4 == 164, so the C# version is supplying the correct value. [Looks like `byte` is signed in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html)